# For csv file one value is "abc",llc this is getting split into two when I open in excel. I tried to double quote it is not working

Tags: excel, csv

How to display "abc",llc name  in one cell

It is displayed separately "abc"
Llc separately. Is there any special character I can add in csv file so it can prevent from displayed in two cells .And displayed as same in excel without changing delimiters

Answer (score 0):

So for that I would replace

```
"abc",llc
```

with

```
"abc"_llc
```

as the comma is designated as the separator, based on the file being CSV ie Comma Separated Variable.

Then you can re-replace the _ with comma later if appropriate.